# Convert Scrollview contentOffset to string

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, contentoffset

Im trying to convert the `contentOffset` from a ScrollView into a string.

I have tried many ways but the closest I got was:

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint([self.mainScrollView contentOffset])];
```

This worked but I the label has the value inside `{}`

```
{0, 0}
```

Does anyone know how to remove the `{}` or have a better way?
Thanks

EDIT:
about 30 seconds after asking I found this to work:

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02f KM", _mainScrollView.contentOffset.y];
```

Thanks for everyones help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following code

```
NSString *contentOffSet = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint([self.mainScrollView contentOffset])];;
NSString *removeBreckets = [contentOffSet stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"{}"]];
label.text = removeBreckets;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the indiviual values of a CGPoint struct:

```
CGPoint point = CGPointMake(10, 100);
CGFloat x = point.x;
CGFloat y = point.y;
```

Use these in a string:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf, %lf", x, y];
```